# Crear columna fecha en múltiples tablas a partir del nombre de la base de datos

Tags: r

Tengo 60 bases de datos en Excel. El nombre de cada una está compuesto por la fecha (mes y año). Necesito crear en cada base la columna `fecha` que le corresponde para después unirlas.

He conseguido importar las bases a R, pero no sé como generar la fecha a partir de la información del nombre de cada dataset. Como son muchos archivos no quiero realizarla manualmente.

Los nombres que tienen son: `balance_enero_2015`, `balance_febrero_2015`, `balance_marzo_2015`, y así sucesivamente hasta `balance_enero_2022`.

---

los archivos son en excel, los nombres que tienen son balance_enero_2015, balance_febrero_2015, balance_marzo_2015  así sucesivamente hasta balance_enero_2022, cada archivo no tiene una variable de fecha, se requiere agregar a cada archivo la variable fecha utilizando el nombre de la variable.

Comment: Me hago una idea muy vaga de lo que buscas, ¿La fecha saldría del nombre del archivo? ¿cómo son estos nombres? ¿Cómo estas importando los arhchivos? sería mejor si pudieras agregar un ejemplo concreto con código.

Comment: Como menciona Patricio se necesita mas detalle para poder ayudar. Por ejemplo, agrega algunos nombres de las bases, una muestra del formato de tus datos originales y lo que esperas obtener.
La idea que se me ocurre es crear un vector con el nombre de los datos. A partir de este vector generar un ciclo que lea cada una de las bases, le agregue la fecha y la guarde en una lista. Para finalizar unes los datos de la lista.

Answer (score 1):

En esta solución se abordan 3 puntos

- Leer varios archivos xlsx a la vez en R
- Asignar el nombre de cada archivo como variable
- Extraer la fecha del nombre

Según entiendo el problema y aun suponiendo que los archivos a leer son del formato `xlsx`. El siguiente código seria una solución

```
# ==========================================================================
# LEER VARIOS ARCHIVOS XLSX
# ==========================================================================


#Paquete para leer archivos xlsx
#nstall.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)


# Obtener los nombres de los datos
#'data' es el nombre de la carpeta donde yo guarde los datos
# Asegurate de cambiarla en caso de que tu carpeta se llame
# diferente

#Leemos los nombres
nombres <- list.files('data')
#agregamos data/ para corregir la direccion de los datos 
nombres <- paste0('data/',nombres)
nombres

#Usamos lapply para generar un ciclo en el que se leen todos los archivos
df<-lapply(nombres,function(x){
    #Se leen los datos
    aux <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile=x)
    #Se asigan el nombre a la columna fecha
    aux$fecha<-x
    return(aux)
})

#Combinamos en un df la lista que regresa lapply
df <- do.call(rbind, df)

#Empezamos a dar formato a la fecha
#Extraemos solo el mes y el año
df$fecha <- regmatches(df$fecha, regexpr("[[:alpha:]]+\\_\\d+", df$fecha))

#Definimos la configuración regional para leer fechas en español
Sys.setlocale(locale="es_ES.UTF-8")

#Convertimos la fecha de carácter a Date
df$fecha<-as.Date(paste0('01',df$fecha),format='%d%B_%Y')
```

Aun si los archivos no son `xlsx` el procedimiento general seria el mismo, solo tendrías que cambiar la función de lectura de los datos.